# Can I draw curved diagonal lines in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I want to draw lines like this (see image below) in Visio
but in order to achive this I have to use 3 separate lines (bottom image).

Is there a simplier way?

[image]

**UPD:**
Im using Visio 2013

**To be more specific. This is what im trying to achieve:**

[image]

Note the placement of pink line. First it goes down and then it turns right on diagonal.

In Visio whatever connector I choose, it wont go in that way by itself.
I weither have to make custom shapes or play with rounding options which is hard.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: For future seekers: I switched to Adobe Illustrator at the end. It has better tools for that

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: You didn't mention what version of Visio you are using. I am using 2007, so this answer works for that version. I'm also assuming you are referring to connector lines. If not, please [edit] your answer to clarify.*

Connector properties can be changed by going to `File > Page Setup > Layout and Routing` tab. Change the appearance to `Curved`. You may have to adjust other settings to get it the way you like it.

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. Not exacly what I want. I've updated my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description there's a simple way to accomplish this. The instructions are for Visio 2013 but the same essential technique will work for earlier versions.

Let's start with a single shape with corners that are not rounded.

[image]

Now select the shape and go to Line Options

[image]

Now you can use the Rounding Presets or Rounding Size to make the corners curve.

[image]

As you can see the line retains its original basic shape, but just the corners are rounded.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. I've updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Now that I see clearly that you are trying to use connectors ... As far as I know none of the connectors in Visio can be laid out in a diagonal way that you want. It *might* be possible that someone has built a connector that can do this but I've never seen one. Please do ask you question on the Visio Guy forums:

http://www.visguy.com/vgforum/

There are a lot of Visio experts there that might know of a connector like this.